# Getting this radiant but soft glow, without losing color intensity or looking overexposed?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photo-editing, light, reverse-engineering

I see photos like this sometimes that look, almost, like the subject is glowing or is suffused with light. (I don't know how else to describe it.) I seem unable to get this effect without just making my picture look overexposed. Is it simply a matter of lifting highlights (like someone suggested on a thread about a different effect)?

If I lift the black point or decrease contrast, that seems to make the photo look washed out. But this looks quite vivid – which I like – just quite soft at the same time. Is it shadow-related? Or perhaps I'm perceiving color adjustments as lighting adjustments and the key is related to saturation... ?

Lightroom answers requested unless there's a PS action or something you would suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a result like this by creating a duplicate layer on Photoshop, and giving it a Gaussian Blur, then lowering the opacity of that layer. This gives the image a radiant glowing effect. Also, Joshua Cripps does a good tutorial on this effect. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGNctntIOx8
Hope this is the effect you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

In Light room with the help of adjustment brush tool you can achieve this soft glow effect.
You have to brush the highlighted area with the brush and decrease clarity and sharpen levels to maximum..
At this point please increase the highlight little bit so that the glow will blurry and soft